# Using structures sort txt file according to lexicographic order and dynamically allocate memory

Tags: c, struct

> Use a structure `tele`, whose components are the name
>   (character array) and telephone number (integer). The character array must use dynamic memory allocation.
>
> You are required to store the directory entries in an array of tele’s, sorted according to the names following lexicographic ordering.The array should be populated using dynamic memory allocation.
>
> ```
>     tele *phonelist;
> ```
>
> Read the values of name and number from the file **directory.txt**, one line at a
>   time, to fill the elements of this array of ‘tele’s.
>
> Now, write a function to sort the elements of this array as per lexicographical order. Once the elements are sorted, print these elements to a file “sorted-names.txt”, in the same format as in “directory.txt”.

**Input File:** (50 such lines)

```
80043   CHEBIYYAM
80131   SHUKLA
80200   GANGARAPU
85400   GAURAV
80001   MUDIT
80345   VISHU
80956   GUNASHEKAR
```

**Code:**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define telenum 100

typedef struct {
   char *name;
   int number;
} tele[telenum];

char **readnames(char fname[], int n) {
   FILE *fp;
   tele t;
   int i, l;
   char **A, buf[1024];

   fp = (FILE *)fopen(fname, "r");
   if (fp == NULL) {
      fprintf(stderr, "Error: unable to open file...\n");
      n = 0;
      return NULL;
   }

   A = (char **)malloc((n) * sizeof(char *));
   for (i = 1; i < n; ++i) {
      fscanf(fp, "%s", t.name);
      l = strlen(t.name);
      A[i] = (struct *)malloc((l + 1) * sizeof(struct));
      strcpy(A[i],t.name);
   }
   fclose(fp);
   return A;
}

void sortnames(char **A, int n) {
   char *t;
   int i, j;

   for (j = n - 2; j >= 0; --j) {
      for (i = 0; i <= j; ++i) {
         if (strcmp(A[i], A[i + 1]) > 0) {
            t = A[i];
            A[i] = A[i + 1];
            A[i + 1] = t;
         }
      }
   }
}

void printnames(char **A, int n) {
   int i;

   for (i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
     printf("%s\n", A[i]);
     free(A[i]);
   }
   free(A);
}

int main() {
   char **names;
   char **names_print;
   int n;

   names = readnames("directory.txt", telenum);
   sortnames(names, telenum);
   printnames(names, telenum);
}
```

**Expected Output:**

```
80043 CHEBIYYAM
80200 GANGARAPU
85400 GAURAV
80956 GUNASHEKAR
80001 MUDIT
80131 SHUKLA
80345 VISHU
```

Comment: What exactly is the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you declared `char **A` and then you allocated memory for it like this:

`A = (char **)malloc((n) * sizeof(char *));`

but here your allocating memory for `A` as a struct:

`A[i] = (struct *)malloc((l+1) * sizeof(struct));`

while `A` is a `char**` data .This should be:

`A[i] = (char *)malloc((l+1) * sizeof(char));`

also note that **casting result of malloc** is not a good work (like this problem) and it is not needed.
read this: ([Do I cast the result of malloc?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc))